# Python 3 - How to randomize what text displays

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am a beginner at python and I am trying to figure out how I can randomly display text. For example, 60% chance of "Hello", 40% chance of saying "Goodbye", etc. Right now, for fun, I am trying to create sort of a bottle flip game. If you don't know what it is, its basically when you flip a half empty water bottle and try to land it. This is what I have: (This is more than likely completely wrong.)

```
import random

number = random.randrange(10)

if number == "1":
    print ("You have landed the bottle!")
elif number == "2":
    print ("You have landed the bottle!")
elif number == "3":
    print ("You have landed the bottle!")
elif number == "4":
    print ("You have landed the bottle!")
elif number == "5":
    print ("The bottle did not land, better luck next time.")
elif number == "6":
    print ("The bottle did not land, better luck next time.")
elif number == "7":
    print ("The bottle did not land, better luck next time.")
elif number == "8":
    print ("The bottle did not land, better luck next time.")
elif number == "9":
    print ("The bottle did not land, better luck next time.")
elif number == "10":
    print ("The bottle landed on the cap!")
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Tip 1: use code formatting instead of quotes, please [edit] your question. Tip 2: what is the question?

Comment: Look at [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module

Comment: You may want to know that `random.randrange(10)` returns a *number*, but you are comparing against *strings*

Comment: [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) accepts weights of the choices with the `p` kwarg.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, basically, but you can greatly simplify your code.

```
if number < 5:
    print ("You have landed the bottle!")
elif number < 10:
    print ("The bottle did not land, better luck next time.")
else:
    print ("The bottle landed on the cap!")
```

You can change the values in your call to `randrange` and in the if statements above to get just about any weighting you'd like.

Note that in your original question you were comparing numbers to strings. I changed that here. Comparing numbers to strings (i.e. `3 == "3"`) will always be `False`.

Comment: You should probably note that comparing strings and integers is wrong which is a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a list of the possible solutions.

```
import random
possibilities=['landed'] * 3 + ['missed'] * 6 + ['landed on cap'] 
print(random.choice(possibilities))
```